# How to use typeahead.js as a Bower component with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use typeahead.js in my Rails 4 app. I would like to use Bower to do this instead of using the gem. I have installed it in `vendor/assets/components`. I have also included the line below in `config/application.rb`.

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')
```

I have searched extensively but cannot seem to figure out what exactly I should include in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` to get Rails to recognize this. The directory `typeahead.js` is installed properly in `vendor/assets/components`. I have tried

```
//= require typeahead.js
```

as well a few other options but it's not working. I'm a relative newbie to Rails and am still trying to figure out how some of the things work under the hood. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use typeahead.js after I posted my question, but need to use it now and got it to work. First of all I didn't need to add anything to `config/application.rb` since the `vendor/assets` directory is already included in the asset pipeline.

Bower installed the directory `typeahead.js` in the `vendor/assets/components` directory as I put

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

in my `.bowerrc` file.

And in my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` I include the full path to the `typeahead.jquery.min.js` file:

```
//= require typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.jquery.min.js
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead you use [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/). Getting started is as simple as adding

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap' #example
  gem 'rails-assets-angular' #example
  gem 'rails-assets-leaflet' #example
end
```

to your Gemfile, replacing the examples with bower assets you need. Simply prefix a given Bower asset with "rails-assets-", and you're good to go.

Be sure to check out their website if you need any help getting started!

Answer (score 0):

Your bower.json file should specify a "typeahead" dependency like this:

```
"vendor": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated vendor assets",
    "dependencies": {
        "typeahead": "git@github.com:twitter/typeahead.js.git"
    }
}
```

Run `rake bower:install`, it should place the library in `vendor/assets/bower_components`

Then in your application.js
`//= require typeahead`